# Pandas add a new column whose values depend on a specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column called 'Date; that contains the date in the format month/day/year('01/01/2018'). I want to create a new column called 'Month' that will contain the name of the month, in this example january.
Obviously i want to do that for each month.

Ex:

```
   Date         Month
0  01/01/2018   January
1  02/03/2018   February
2  04/08/2018   April
```

How can i do it?
Thank you

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ Please read the `calendar` documentation. Hint: the "_abbr" in `calendar.month_abbr` means "abbreviated".

Comment: Ok i solved the problem using this link. Thank you

Comment: @DYZ `calendar.month_name` will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming 'Date' in df is `string` , hence the need to convert.
If not you will need to adjust accordingly.

Try following

```
from datetime import date,datetime  #date needed for simulation.
import pandas as pd


l = ['01/01/2018','02/03/2018','04/08/2018']  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':l})

df['Month']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x :datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%B'))
```

**Result**

```
>>> df
         Date     Month
0  01/01/2018   January
1  02/03/2018  February
2  04/08/2018     April
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simply way to solve the problem:

**Code**

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd
d = {'Date':['01/01/2018', '02/03/2018', '04/08/2018']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['Date']).month
df1['Month'] = df1['Month'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[x])
print(df1)
```

On executing this code, you will end up at the desired result:

**Result**

```
         Date      Month
0  01/01/2018    January
1  02/03/2018   February
2  04/08/2018      April
```